# XAML editor won't render the controls in my WPF window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

As of recently Visual C# 2012's XAML editor won't render any controls. I don't get any error messages or warnings and I can still select the controls. I just don't see them. Here's what it looks like in the editor:

[image: XAML editor]

The source code of the XAML file can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/pieterdd/calendarwatch/src/0c7a119f4650d88938ebc9f730d69e9accb7a915/CalendarWatch/NfyWindow.xaml). Oddly enough all my other XAML files are displaying normally. At runtime, the controls in the faulty XAML file also render normally. As you can see in the screenshot, the error list is empty.

Why isn't my XAML file rendering in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `Opacity="0"` from the window root tag makes the controls show in my Visual Studio.

I tried to switch the opacity on back in case if code is running in the designer like this:

```
public NfyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        this.Opacity = 1;
}
```

—but this seems to be ignored by Visual Studio 2010.

However the reverse trick helps: you can remove the opacity setting from the XAML and put it into the constructor. This worked for me, but your Visual Studio version/SP may be different.

You may also try a cleaner way:

```
public NfyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        this.Opacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: D'oh... I looked right past that `Opacity` attribute. Ah well, your little trick is working smoothly here! Now I can edit the controls without breaking the fade in animation. Thanks for the tip!